# How can I convert an absolute system path to an IShellFolder?

Tags: php, .net, windows, com

I will preface this by saying that I have absolutely zero experience using COMs, let alone using them through PHP's [COM extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php).

As part of a larger project, I need to get the [`IShellFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775075%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that represents a given absolute system path. I've done a lot of googling and most of the solutions I ran into involved utilizing [`SHGetDesktopFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but the combination of the syntax differences (since all the examples I've seen are in some .NET language or other) and the fact that `Desktop` will likely **not** be an ancestor of the path that I am looking for are confusing me.

In case it is relevant to the answer, my end goal is to use the `IShellFolder` to retrieve the `IExtractImage` for a given file within the `IShellFolder` and display the image on the server that the script is running on.

Comment: Although it may sound weird, Desktop *is* indeed the root path of all shell folders. Also, beware of calling Shell API on a server. It's not always supported.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there are special facilities in PHP, but in C or C++ Raymond Chen recommends using [`SHParseDisplayName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762236%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert the absolute path into a `PIDL`, and then [`SHBindToParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762114%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that gives you both the `IShellFolder` pointer and the `PCUITEMID_CHILD` of the file within the folder.

([His example function `GetUIObjectOfFile`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/20/231739.aspx) goes the extra mile and binds to the object itself, though that may not be what you want)

However, since it makes you deal with a PIDL in addition to the rest, it may be worse than the `SHGetDesktopFolder` method.